# Understanding how to count the characters in a string in order to use slice() on a part of the string

Tags: javascript, string

I am learning JavaScript , the fundamentals for now and what I don’t get, is how to count the characters in the string in order to use the slice on the certain string and extract a certain word out of the string.
For example

```
let text = "JavaScript", "apples", "avocado");
let newText = text.slice(?),(?);
```

How do I know or count the position of apples for example or JavaScript?
Thank you!

Comment: Is that meant to be an array of strings, and you want to find the position of one of the elements?

Comment: For example I want to slice out or replace a certain word from those 3 but I will need to insert its positions, when using slice() we need to insert the start and the end. Like in this example On W3school let str = "Apple, Banana, Kiwi";
let part = str.slice(7, 13);

Comment: Use split, not slice and fix up your question because the code makes no sense. You’ve got too many quotes going on.

Comment: @GabrielMihai I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
let text = "JavaScript, apples, avocado";
let newText = text.slice(text.indexOf("JavaScript"));
let newText2 = text.slice(text.indexOf("apples"));
console.log(newText)
console.log(newText2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string into an array, , and then [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in the string you do want. Finally, [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array elements into a new string.

```js
const str = 'JavaScript, apples, avocado';

function replace(str, search, replacement) {

  // Create an array using `split`
  const arr = str.split(', ');
  
  // Find the index of the item you're looking for
  const index = arr.findIndex(el => el === search);

  // `splice` in the new replacement string
  arr.splice(index, 1, replacement);

  // Return the new string
  return arr.join(', ');
  
}

console.log(replace(str, 'apples', 'biscuit'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Few observations/suggestions **:**

- String will always wrapped with the quotes but in your post it is not looks like a string.
- Why you want to slice to get the word from that string ? You can convert that string into an array and then get that word.

Implementation steps **:**

- Split string and convert that in an array using [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.
- Now we can find for the word you want to search from an array using [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Input string
const text = "JavaScript, apples, avocado";
const searchText = 'apples';

// Split string and convert that in an array using String.split() method.
const splittedStringArray = text.split(',');

// Now we can find for the word from splittedStringArray using Array.find() method.
const result = splittedStringArray.find(item => item.trim() === searchText);

// Output
console.log(result);
```